# Adding items to scrollview in storyboard (size inspector appears to be locked)

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiscrollview, storyboard

I've added a scrollview with a content size that is larger than the screen size in my view controller using storyboard. Of course the purpose of the scrollview is to have content larger than the view that contains it. I would like to add buttons and label to the bottom of the scrollview graphically in storyboard, but I can't view  that part of the scrollview. How do I get there. I tried adjusting in the size inspector which worked for me when I first added the view a few weeks ago, but it don't let me change anything.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The only way I've been able to edit my content in a `UIScrollView` (and this dates back to way before the Storyboard, but I'm pretty sure it still applies) is to change the offset of the  x or y of your content frame.

Another option, depending on whether your content view is "static" (built in the .xib) or not, is to actually pull it outside of the scroll view, and set it as the content view programmatically in `viewDidLoad` or something.

Hope this helps, I can follow up with code examples if it makes sense and you need 'em.

EDIT (2/10/2012): Here's an example of how to hook up the larger view to your scroll view. In this example, the scroll view (scrollView) is set to the view controller's view property. In the .xib I've also added a `UIView` named largerView. The two are not hooked up in any way in the .xib file, they just both appear there.

Given...

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *largeView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
```

In `viewDidLoad:` we just...

```
// add the largeView to the main scrollView
[scrollView addSubview:largeView];
[scrollView setContentSize:largeView.frame.size];
```

This is probably the simplest possible example though. Good luck!

Comment: I went back and looked at this again. I discovered the scroll view that has content larger than the view in storyboard was the top level view of the view controller. When configured like this you can't adjust the x and y offset in the size inspector. However, if a uiview is the top level and the scroll view is placed in that, then the content offset (x and y under "view" in the size inspector) can be adjusted exposing different areas of the scrollview in storyboard so they can be configured. Problem solved!

Comment: Code examples would be great! :)

Comment: Added a code example for hooking a view to a scroll view programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

It's great that you solved that. If I had that problem I would create a view that has the same frame size as content size of the scroll view. Add all the controls I need (buttons, labels, textFields etc.) on this view at the positions I need. After that just added the view on scroll, make an IBOutlet of the scroll and set it's content size programmatically somewhere in my code, before using that scroll (setting it in viewDidLoad will be fine).

That's another solution of this problem.

Comment: I like that too. I'll give it a go next time I'm in that situation.

Comment: This is what I suggested also.

Answer (score 1):

@T.J. & @livingtech:

Why don't you use embed property given in Interface Builder?

Here you are creating two views (UIView largeView and UIScrollView scrollView). So its kind of  wasting of memory for the same objects.

[image]

1. First add one more UIView in your nib with your height and width.
2. Add your controls wherever you want.  (let say *largeView* only)
3. Then use embed property with ScrollView. (let say *myScrollView* only)
4. Now add this *myScrollView* in your original view wherever you want with your custom height and width.
5. In code base just set *myScrollView* contentSize as per the *largeView* size.

This would be easier for the code reusability and expandability purpose. If in future you need to add more objects.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I'm following you here, but I think this is still the same number of objects as what I suggested. I'm pretty sure you always need a `UIView` to be the content view of your `UIScrollView`.

Comment: the OP isn't using a nib. If T.J. were, you could drag a scroll view onto the nib canvas, resize it,etc so you could fit all the views you want in it, then resize it back and either add it to the subview in code, or, drag it back as a subview within the nib using the hierarchy view (you can't do it by dragging and dropping the actual view widgets in the canvas). But, this strategy doesn't appear to work within the storyboard editor.

Answer (score -1):

You can work on iPad Full Screen size if your content won't exceed the screen size too much.