# iPhone - Edit storyboard elements in separate window

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiscrollview, storyboard

I am trying to edit a UIView inside a UIScrollView. I have set the UIView's hight to 700, but I can't scroll around to place objects. I want to open the UIView in a separate window to edit its content. Or, is there another way I should be approaching this? The first answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9118796/steps-for-creating-uiscrollview-with-interface-builder) question contains an example of what I am trying to do, although in storyboard. What am I doing wrong, or is it possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9288070/visually-arrange-subviews-in-a-large-uiscrollview) link was the best solution. I was able to get Devin's solution to partly work, but it involved a lot of hacking with my code. While the above link disables auto-layout, I am ok with that for my small application.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a separate XIB file for the UIView you are going to be creating, then create a new class as the file owner of this XIB. You would then want to connect the UIView inside your UIScrollView to this.

The steps involved are illustrated in this past question:
[Add subview from a xib or another scene with storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754157/add-subview-from-a-xib-or-another-scene-with-storyboard)

Comment: I have tried this, and I get stuck in an infinite loop when adding the xib.... Any other ideas? Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Can you post some of your code?  Also, where is the infinite loop happening?  I don't understand where that would occur.

Comment: That will take some time, but I will certainly work on it. What would be best to pull?

Comment: Well I just don't understand where you are getting an infinite loop.  Can you explain that more?

Comment: I am getting it in the `initWithCoder` call (from the example). It is trying to load my xib, but it just gets stuck forever. I have changed the name to match my xib, and it gives no errors, and does not crash.